# Is translation an option in Drupal 8's logger?

Tags: i18n-l10n

Drupal 7's `watchdog()` function has a transaltable `$message` and a `$variables` argument.

The logger in Drupal 8 doesn't seem to have option. Is it recommended to pass the output of `t()` to logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't use `t()` for logger messages. The messages are going to be translated already and you don't want to translate twice.

Example for the cron message:

```
    $logger->notice('Starting execution of @module_cron(), execution of @module_previous_cron() took @time.', [
      '@module' => $module,
      '@module_previous' => $module_previous,
      '@time' => Timer::read('cron_' . $module_previous) . 'ms',
    ]);
```

This is the same as in a `t()` function. The difference is that the messages are stored untranslated and will only be translated on runtime so that the message can be displayed in each user's language.